# Java Button Triggers Multiple Events

Tags: java, event-handling, inner-classes

I'm learning some basic Java working on a task using inner classes to create a two button gui. One button changes the colour of a drawn circle and one changes the text of a label. The problem I'm having is that when I click the change label button the circle colour changes as well (on the first click, nothing happens thereafter). If I click the change colour button it operates as expected changing only the circle colour on each click. Basically I would like to try and understand why this happens.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TwoButtons {

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TwoButtons gui = new TwoButtons ();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go () {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
        labelButton.addActionListener(new LabelListener());

        JButton colorButton = new JButton("Change Colour");
        colorButton.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

        label = new JLabel("I'm a label");
        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel { 
             public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {      
                 g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                 int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                 int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                 int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                 Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
                 g.setColor(randomColor);
                 g.fillOval(140,140,300,300); 
             }
         }

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colorButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, label);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class LabelListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                label.setText("Boom!"); 
            }
    }

    class ColorListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `MyDrawPanel` code.

Comment: What you want to achieve by `repaint()` ?

Comment: @talex The MyDrawPanel Code is as follows; 

`class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
 
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  
  g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
  
  int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
  int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
  int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
  
  Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
  g.setColor(randomColor);
  g.fillOval(140,140,300,300);
 }
}`

Comment: @joeyrohan The purpose of the repaint is to generate a new random colour for the circle when the change colour button is clicked.

Comment: @Jonny You can edit your original question. Put it there. It will be formatted properly and anyone who want to answer will have all information in one place.

Comment: @talex - Facepalm, question edited. I was aware you could edit questions, I plainly deactivated brain before responding yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I guess whenever a Component of a JFrame is changed, the Frame repaints automatically. Because after you click the label button for the first time the text doesn't change anymore, repaint isn't automatically called after clicking the label button.

Answer (score 0):

In you `paintComponent` method you get new value of color component each time.
Problem is that this method can be invoked for lots of reason not only when you invoke `repaint`.

I suggest you get field `Color randomColor` in your `TwoButtons` class and move code

```
int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

before `frame.repaint();` in `ColorListener`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work, I should note that I don't actually know where the MyDrawPanel code is coming from, though I suspect it might be another class in the same directory. Where I included it within the two buttons class was purely for illustrative purposes, in my own code it was just commented out at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I didn't understand. It doesn't work or you unable to do it because have no access to code of `MyDrawPanel`?